# Getting Null value of date in controller from view by using view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC. I am facing problem to get Date of birth value from view into controller by using view model. I am using view model for getting form values and getting all other textboxes values. But I always get null value for date.

My view model is like this.

```
  public class Student
  {
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date of birth is required")]
       [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yy}",ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false)]
       public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
  }
```

My controller which is called after form posting is:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult StudentPersonalReg(Student stud)
    {
        DateTime? dateofbirth = stud.DateOfBirth;     
        return RedirectToAction("Registration");
    }
```

My view is

```
  @model eEducation.Models.UserModel.Student

   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfBirth)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DateOfBirth)
```

Problem is that I always get null value for date in controller.
I have also tried setting DateTime.Now to the viewmodel when I am calling the view from controller.

I am not using strongly typed view.

Please help me in this regard.

I am passing my model to view by controller method

```
    public ViewResult Registration()
    {
        var db = new eEducationEntities();
        List<CountryMaster> queryCountry = db.CountryMasters.ToList();         

        List<StateMaster> queryState = db.StateMasters.ToList();


        Student stds = new Student();

        stds.Countries = queryCountry;
        stds.States = queryState;
        stds.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;

        return View("~/Views/UserSection/StudentRegistration.cshtml", stds);
    }
```

Comment: Are you actually passing your model to your view ? All I see is a Redirect (which is not the same as loading a view).

Comment: Yes, I am also passing my model to view which is perform by another controller method

Comment: I got the reason of problem. It was because of culture. Default culture is en-US. Where I want date in dd/MM/yyyy. But still cannot find solution. If I will be able to set culture Info in master layout then I think it would lead the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using a Html.BeginForm() on your view model. You can even specify the controller action it posts back to.

```
@model eEducation.Models.UserModel.Student

@using (Html.BeginForm("StudentPersonalReg", "ControllerName")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfBirth)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DateOfBirth)

<p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
}
```

Comment: I am already using this. If I was not using not form then how cound I get other value except date of birth as I have already mentioned.

Comment: Apologies, however, if you don't post the code how am I supposed to know you're using it? So many people make that mistake so I can't just assume you haven't if I have no evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Oh! no. You don't to need to apologize. Just solve this problem. I shall be grateful to you.